# Laravel PHPUNIT how do you test the queries requests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, request, phpunit

I have a function (data) on my application controller that makes the data tables (does all the queries to find the information **and** sent the request to the application(the data with all the information that the queries returned)).
The thing that I want to test is:

When the requests are made to the network if they are slow (or have some delay).

How many SQL requests are made.

How do I do this PHPUnit test on Laravel?

I added the clockwork debug tool to give me some additional information.

Comment: Why are you testing 1? Two can be done pretty easily using database [listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#listening-for-query-events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope).

There is list of Youtube lessons for "laravel Telescope":

- [Laravel Telescope - Features & Examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctU0FWbutHs)
- [Laravel 5.8 Tutorial From Scratch - e41 - Telescope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeGbPeM3_m8)
- [What is Laravel Telescope? A full guide to install and set up Laravel Telescope.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e66S7r3LOW0)
- [Laravel Telescope | Awesome Debugging Tool #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQsCoSKRaZo)